# Securing UI in a one page js application

Tags: javascript, security, backbone.js, ember.js

Let me start off by saying that I do understand that one should never attempt to secure anything in javascript on the client side.  My question is referring to UI that some users would see and others would not.  Usually this UI also has some sort of logic bound to it.  Whether it be Backbone or Ember, what are some of the normal practices for showing or hiding different parts of the UI depending on user roles.

My initial thought was to load different js depending on the currently signed in user.  On top of this, loading view templates async also came to mind.  I would love to hear other ideas and patterns though.  Keep in mind that this is assuming the backend API that the client communicates with is already secure for the given user.  So even if they were to view a secure UI component, it would not work correctly.

Comment: Whatever you do, the back end needs to do the validation to make sure they have the rights to make the calls.

Comment: Yes I am indeed securing and validating in the backend.  Its just a matter of showing or not showing UI components in a secure way.  One that does not allow someone with a js console to flip a few booleans to render views they shouldn't be able to see even if those views do not contain any sensitive data since it wouldn't be passed from the server.

Comment: But if they flipped the boolean, it would not matter since the backend should not feed the data to the front end. AKA, they can not delete an account because the backend would never allow that request to happen. If you code your code to extend from a base class, it is not hard to add admin features onto the other code by just adding another JavaScript file.

Comment: @epascarello So you are in agreement that adding another js file for the authorized to extend the base is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this actually is a security question. The security is handled by the server anyway. It has more to do with how you organise javascript when your application has different modes.

I don't think it would be a good idea to have a totally different set of javascript files for the two modes. You should rather try to separate data and functionality and provide different data in each mode. I.e. if you have a menu, don't hard code all menu entries but make an ajax call to the server and load the menu items. Let the server provide different menu items based on the users permissions.

Some functionality would of course only be relevant in the admin mode. It would be perfectly fine to put that in a separate file.